# Postgres: Loop through json array equivalent in SQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am using postgres 9.6.3 and need to convert the following python code to a sql query:

```
data = response.json()
activities = data['Response']['data']['activities']
for activity in activities:
    activityHash = int(activity['activityHash'])
    if activityHash == 2659248071:
        clears = int(activity['values']['activityCompletions']['basic']['value'])
```

The table has two columns: (membershipid integer primary key, data jsonb). I am not sure how to handle an array like this in sql. The array is variable length and might or might not include an entry where activityHash == the desired value.

The desired result from the query would be something like SELECT membershipid, clears FROM table.

Comment: What do you actually want it to do? Do you have any SQL to start with?

Comment: Aside of the SQL equivalent, do you know about [`PL/Python`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpython.html)?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for jsonb_array_elements(activities)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check out this [link](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-query-jsonb-beginner-sheet-cheat-4da3aa5082a3) that walks you through how to traverse JSONB in Postgres.

Try the following query and see if that works for you:

```
SELECT
membershipid,
'data' -> 'activity' -> 'response' -> 'data' -> 'activities' ->> 'activityHash' AS activityHash,
'data' -> 'activity' -> 'response' -> 'data' -> 'activities' -> 'activityHash' -> 'values' -> 'activityCompletions' -> 'basic' ->> 'value' AS clears

FROM yourtablename

WHERE
('data' -> 'activity' -> 'response' -> 'data' -> 'activities' ->> 'activityHash')::int = 2659248071;
```